# What is inf in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, numeric-limits

I am debugging a C++ program. There is a variable `x` of type double, gdb prints its value as `inf`. Yet, the following expression returns `false` even though the value of `x` did not change

`x == std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`

When gdb says `inf`, does it not mean the max possible value for this type (double)? If not, then what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `x == std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`.

A floating point implementation doesn't *necessarily* have to support infinity but the common one - IEEE754 - does.

From C++11 onwards, you can use `std::isinf(x)` to test if a floating point number is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, infinity is not the maximum value; in this sense, it's not a "value" at all.

Infinity, like NaN, is a "special value" that your IEEE754 floating-point numbers can take. The two of them exhibit unusual properties (e.g. NaN != NaN) and do not sit on the number line in what is otherwise the numerical range of your chosen floating-point type.

Although 1.79769e+308 (`std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` on my system) is a very large number, it's a *long* way off being infinity. Every single potential value in between (and there is literally an infinity of them) is unrepresentable in this type. The "min" and "max" functions would not be useful with regards to the numerical domain of `double`, if they merely returned `-inf` and `inf`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure +INF and -INF sit on the number line. In particular, they sit at either end. More formally, both infinities are ordered with respect to the finite numbers.

Comment: Also, " Every single potential value in between 1.79E308 and +INF (and there is literally an infinity of them)" is a bit misleading. There are exactly as many rational numbers between 1.0 and 2.0, or between 0.01 and 0.02, or pi and e. Math can be rather counter-intuitive, I admit.

Comment: A definition of this *kind* of infinity that I find particularly useful is a number x that is greater than y for any value of y.

Comment: @MSalters: They do not and the functions `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` prove — even _define_ — that. You should read the whole of the sentence you refer to - I'm talking about the number line of _the numerical range of your chosen floating-point type_.

Comment: @MSalters: _"There are exactly as many rational numbers between 1.0 and 2.0, or between 0.01 and 0.02, or pi and e"_ Again, no. Floating-point types have a fixed precision. This is `double`, not abstract rational numbers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Of course the representable `double` values are an infinitely sparse subset. That's why that set isn't a line, it's not continuous. My second point is that _any_ range in ℝ contains an infinite number of "potential values", so your claim about the specific range `std::numeric_limits<double>::max(), +INF` is vacuous.